# how to compare the two fields in same input xml data using xslt?

Tags: xslt

Can anyone please help me out from this.
Actually thing is when you compare with "ID"s, if "ID"s are equals ,it return "bb" or what are input we having in input xml. if it has not equal,some thing will return.I will be all input and xslt coding provided in screenshot.

Thanks for advance.

Myxslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="Emps/Emp">
<xsl:variable name="Result1" select="Id[1]"></xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="Result2" select="Id[2]"></xsl:variable>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test='compare($Result1) = ($Result2)'>
     <xsl:value-of-select="$Result1"/>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of-select="$Result2"/>
   </xsl:otherwise>                
</xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required Output:
 `<Name>bb</Name>`

Comment: Here my Input:<Emps>
<Emp>
<Id>1</Id>
<Name>aa</Name>
</Emp>
<Emp>
<Id>1</Id>
<Name>bb</Name>
</Emp>
</Emps>

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the input please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining your `Result1` and `Result2` variables inside a `xsl:for-each` construct. That means they will be local in scope to that block, and not accessible outside it. Additionally, where you use `Id[2]` that will be looking for the second `Id` element under the current `Emp` element, when you really want the `Id` element under the second `Emp` element.

So, replace your `xsl:for-each` with this...

```
<xsl:variable name="Result1" select="Emps/Emp[1]/Id" />
<xsl:variable name="Result2" select="Emps/Emp[2]/Id" />
```

Furthermore, to compare `Result1` and `Result2` you just do `<xsl:when test="$Result1 = $Result2">`

And finally, doing `<xsl:value-of select="$Result1"/>` will output the `Id` value. To output the `Name` you can do this...

```
 <xsl:value-of select="$Result1/following-sibling::Name"/>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="Result1" select="Emps/Emp[1]/Id" />
  <xsl:variable name="Result2" select="Emps/Emp[2]/Id" />
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$Result1 = $Result2">
      <xsl:value-of select="$Result1/following-sibling::Name"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="$Result2/following-sibling::Name"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>                
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, you don't really need variables here. Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="Emps/Emp[1]/Id = Emps/Emp[2]/Id">
      <xsl:value-of select="Emps/Emp[1]/Name"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="Emps/Emp[2]/Name"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>                
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Of course, both of these assume only two `Emp` elements in your XML. I can't help thinking that perhaps you are trying to eliminate duplicate Ids from your XML. If so, you should read up on a technique called [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) (If you are using XSLT 1.0, that is. If you are using XSLT 2.0, you can use `xsl:for-each-group`).

Comment: Thanks for quick response..@.sure I will try this xslt's.

Comment: Once again Thank you so much for help and Its working fine.